# It just wont load pages into divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So this little script was working exactly how i wanted it to but i did something to mess it up, basically i have one jQuery function

```
function loadDiv(id, page) {
    $(function () {
        $("#" + id).load(page);
    });
}
```

and then this HTML (obviously through a for loop)

`<a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadDiv('post_1', '/edit.post.php?id=1')">Edit this Post</a> -->`

I have tried removing "javascript:" I actually tried that because I could think of nothing else wrong.

Comment: What if you pass the parameters of the loadDiv function to $(function)?. `$(function(id, page) {...`, maybe they are not reaching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't think you need the extra jQuery wrapper.

```
function loadDiv(id, page) {
    $(function () {                // what is this line for?
        $("#" + id).load(page);
    });
}
```

I would just keep:

```
function loadDiv(id, page) {
    $("#" + id).load(page);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write your links like so

```
 <a href="#" class="loadTrigger" data-id="post_1" data-page="/edit.post.php?id=1">Edit this Post</a>
```

Then write your function like so

```
 $('body').on('click', '.loadTrigger', function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
      $("#" + id).load(page);
 });
```